# Why my spring @Transactional with REQUIRED can't rollback?

Tags: java, spring, transactional

I try to write a very simple code to test @Transactional, but it won't rollback when I use Propagation.REQUIRED. Here is the code.

```
    @Component
    public class A {

        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        @Resource(name="dataSource")
        public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }

        @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
        public void add(Person person) throws Exception {
        try {
            String sql = "insert into person (id, name) values(?,?)";
            jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new  Object[{person.getId(),person.getName()});
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

        @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
        public void delete(String id) throws Exception {
            throw new RuntimeException();
            ***throw a RuntimeException on purpose***
        }
    }

    public class cases {

        @Transactional
        public static void testPro() throws Exception {
        try {
            AbstractApplicationContext aac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
            A a = (A) aac.getBean("a");
            a.add(***a random person***);
            a.delete("99");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        testPro();
    }
}
```

When I test add() method alone by creating a new RuntimeException(), it will rollback. This is what I expected. However, when I run the test() method, the add() method won't rollback when delete() throws a new RuntimeException. It means the add() and delete()  are not in a same transaction, but what I want is all the things to be rollback. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Transactional` on `testPro()` has no effect for 3 separate reasons:

1. `testPro()` is static.
2. Call is internal from `test()` in same class.
3. Instance of class `cases` not created by Spring.

That means that `add()` and `delete()` are running in two separate transactions.

To prove it, try changing the propagation on `delete()` to `MANDATORY`. It will now throw exception saying that transaction is not in progress *(or something to that effect)*.

Comment: what about the `new jdbcemplate(dataSource)` ? I never used it myself but this seems strange for me.

Comment: @Walfrat That's what you're supposed to do when using Spring JDBC. Perfectly normal.

Comment: You are right. Now I know the two methods are not in a same transaction, but I don't know how to put them into a same transaction. So I removed static and tried to add @Component on the cases and created another calss to call testPro(), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you read the [Testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html) chapters of the Spring documentation?